# Versions of boto3, aiobotocore, awscli, and botocore incompatible; can't be resolved

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli, botocore

If I try to install the latest version of aiobotocore `pip3 install aiobotocore==0.10.3` it says my version of botocore is incompatible and I need an older version of it.

```
ERROR: aiobotocore 0.10.3 has requirement botocore<1.12.190,>=1.12.189, but you'll have botocore 1.12.224 which is incompatible.
```

So if I change my version of botocore to 1.12.189, it breaks `awscli` and `boto3`

```
ERROR: boto3 1.9.224 has requirement botocore<1.13.0,>=1.12.224, but you'll have botocore 1.12.189 which is incompatible.
ERROR: awscli 1.16.234 has requirement botocore==1.12.224, but you'll have botocore 1.12.189 which is incompatible.
```

It doesn't seem like there are versions of the packages that would work with them all. Can someone tell me what versions are all compatible? And is there any way for pip for automatically determine this?

Comment: There's a hack way that you can download `aiobotocore` from github then modify `setup.py`, change `'botocore>=1.12.189,<1.12.190'` to `botocore==1.12.224`. Then run `pip3 install .`. Maybe it's compatible.

Answer (score 8):

try `aioboto3` instead of `boto3` ?

add to `requirements.in`

```
aioboto3
aiobotocore
```

just run

```
 python3.8 -m pip install pip --upgrade
 python3.8 -m pip install pip-tools
 python3.8 -m piptools compile requirements.in
```

and you will get something like

```
#
# This file is autogenerated by pip-compile
# To update, run:
#
#    pip-compile requirements.in
#
aioboto3==8.0.5           # via -r requirements.in
aiobotocore==1.0.4        # via -r requirements.in, aioboto3
aiohttp==3.6.2            # via aiobotocore
aioitertools==0.7.0       # via aiobotocore
async-timeout==3.0.1      # via aiohttp
attrs==19.3.0             # via aiohttp
boto3==1.12.32            # via aiobotocore
botocore==1.15.32         # via aiobotocore, boto3, s3transfer
chardet==3.0.4            # via aiohttp
docutils==0.15.2          # via botocore
idna==2.10                # via yarl
jmespath==0.10.0          # via boto3, botocore
multidict==4.7.6          # via aiohttp, yarl
python-dateutil==2.8.1    # via botocore
s3transfer==0.3.3         # via boto3
six==1.15.0               # via python-dateutil
typing-extensions==3.7.4.2  # via aioitertools
urllib3==1.25.10          # via botocore
wrapt==1.12.1             # via aiobotocore
yarl==1.5.1               # via aiohttp
```